# Access Query - Update Based on Latest Date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I tried to locate an answer for this on other threads and was unable to find one. Please forgive me if it is covered in another thread.

I am relatively new to T-SQL, so please excuse if this is something I should already know.

I have a simple **Access** database with two tables: Contacts and Orders.

Contacts columns are ID (PK), FirstName, LastName, Address, a Status field (identifying if the customer is a "PC", which is who matters in this case), and also has a field for "Delayed." This field is to be "true" for those customers who haven't ordered in the last two months (and "false" for those who have).

The Orders table has the order numbers, along with Customer ID (PK related to Contacts), FirstName, LastName, Date.

I'm trying to write a query to update the "Delayed" field in the Contacts table, based on the latest order date from the Orders table. In this case, update that field to "false" for each PC customer if their latest order date falls within the last 60 days. It seemed pretty striaghtforward, but I'm obviously missing something here. I'm using a SELECT subquery to define the conditions. The query seems to be ignoring my conditions and wants to update ALL rows in the database. Any thoughts?

```
UPDATE Contacts SET Contacts.Delayed = False
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Contacts.FirstName, Contacts.LastName, Contacts.Status, Max(Orders.Date)
FROM Contacts INNER JOIN Orders ON (Contacts.ID = Orders.ContactID)
GROUP BY Contacts.FirstName, Contacts.LastName, Contacts.Status
HAVING Max(Orders.Date) > Date()-60);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"I am relatively new to T-SQL, so please excuse if this is something I should already know."* - The first thing you should know is that Microsoft Access does not use "T-SQL", it uses "Access SQL". T-SQL is the dialect used by Microsoft SQL Server. They are not the same.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware, and I understand they're not the same. While I'm more used to working with T-SQL, Access SQL is similar, but its nuances are a bit frustrating to get used to. :)

Comment: Okay, good. Now is there a particular reason why the question is tagged "sql-server"?

Comment: I'll remove the tag. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using exists, if the query returns a result, all contacts will have their delayed attribute set.

What you want to do is filter the results you are going to update, using a join. You will need a left join, because you want to find orders that haven't taken place within the last two months.

```
UPDATE  tblContacts
SET     Contacts.Delayed = False
FROM    Contacts tblContacts
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  Contacts.FirstName ,
                            Contacts.LastName ,
                            Contacts.Status ,
                            MAX(Orders.Date)
                    FROM    Contacts
                            INNER JOIN Orders ON ( Contacts.ID = Orders.ContactID )
                    GROUP BY Contacts.FirstName ,
                            Contacts.LastName ,
                            Contacts.Status
                    HAVING  MAX(Orders.Date) > Date() - 60
                  ) tbl ON tbl.Contacts.Id = tblContacts.Id
WHERE   tblContacts.Id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Jesse! I'll definitely give this a shot.Once again, excuse my ignorance. Not super strong in Access SQL. Where does the "Contacts_Key" come from?

Comment: No worries Nick! That's why this site is here. If it works for you, don't forget to mark it as the solution ;)

Comment: I think it will probably work, but access is barking because it wants all the JOIN statements to be separated with parentheses. Still trying to figure out how to format the statement to make Access happy... :)